# Using grgit to capture logs between two tags

Tags: git, gradle, groovy, grgit, gradle-git

I want to capture the commit messages between two tags. Like, I create a tag in my repo, then commit some files and then add a tag. So, in between these tags, I want to capture those commit messages. All this is suppose to be done using grgit, the gradle git plugin :

Currently, I can see the logs by using the log operation of grgit plugin like this:

```
def log = grgit.log()

log.each { l ->
    logger.lifecycle("ID: $l.id, Author: $l.author, FullMessage: $l.fullMessage")
}
```

Now, the above method gives me an entire list of logs but I just want between two tags.I am sure, in order to see the logs between two tags, I will have to apply a for loop in place of each and give starting point as tagA and end point as tagB. But I am not so sure how to achieve that correctly. Any pointers!

Comment: Your problem statement is not very clear. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I have edited it. Please read once again and tell me if its still unclear. I ll be even more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the documentation of Grgit for the [log](http://ajoberstar.org/grgit/docs/groovydoc/org/ajoberstar/grgit/operation/LogOp.html) operation, you could do something like this:

```
def log = grgit.log {
  range 'tagA', 'tagB'
}
```